# Get count of matching time ranges for every minute of the day in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-10

## Problem

I have a table of records each containing `id`, `in_datetime`, and `out_datetime`. A record is considered "open" during the time between the `in_datetime` and `out_datetime`. I want to know how many time records were "open" for each minute of the day (regardless of date). For example, for the last 90 days I want to know how many records were "open" at 3:14 am, then 3:15 am, then 3:16 am, then... If no records were "open" at 2:00 am the query should return 0 or null instead of excluding the row, thus 1440 rows should always be returned (the number of minutes in a day). Datetimes are stored in UTC and need to be cast to a time zone.

#### Simplified example graphic

```
record_id | time_range
          | 0123456789 (these are minutes past midnight)
        1 | =========
        2 |      ===
        3 | =======
        4 |    ===
        5 | ==
______________________
result      3323343210
```

#### Desired output

```
time  | count of open records at this time 
00:00   120
00:01   135
00:02   132
...
23:57   57
23:58   62
23:59   60
```

No more than 1440 records would ever be returned as there are only 1440 minutes in the day.

## What I've tried

**1.)** In a subquery, I currently generate a minutely series of times for the entire range of each time record. I then group those by time and get a count of the records per minute. 
[Here is a db-fiddle using my current query:](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aFyHLEapSBwwbuXvNSnhZK/0)

```
select
    trs.minutes,
    count(trs.minutes)
from (
    select
        generate_series(
            DATE_TRUNC('minute', (time_records.in_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver')),
            DATE_TRUNC('minute', (time_records.out_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver')),
            interval  '1 min'
        )::time as minutes
    from
        time_records
) trs
group by
    trs.minutes
```

**This works but is quite inefficient** and takes several seconds to run due to the size of my table. Additionally, it excludes times when no records were open. I think somehow I could use window functions to count the number of overlapping time records for each minute of the day, but I don't quite understand how to do that.

**2.)** Modifying Gordon Linoff's query in his answer below, I came to this ([db-fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n1ibdtf5Ri6oAsiFyYQnaK/1)):

```
with tr as (
    select 
        date_trunc('minute', (tr.in_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver'))::time as m,
        1 as inc
    from
        time_records tr

    union all

    select
        (date_trunc('minute', (tr.out_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver')) + interval '1 minute')::time as m,
        -1 as inc
    from
        time_records tr

    union all

    select
        minutes::time,
        0
    from
        generate_series(timestamp '2000-01-01 00:00', timestamp '2000-01-01 23:59', interval  '1 min') as minutes
)
select
    m,
    sum(inc) as changes_at_inc,
    sum(sum(inc)) over (order by m) as running_count
from
    tr
where
    m is not null
group by 
    m
order by
    m;
```

This runs reasonably quickly, but towards the end of the day (about 22:00 onwards in the linked example) the values turn negative for some reason. Additionally, this query doesn't seem to work correctly with records with time ranges that cross over midnight. It's a step in the right direction, but I unfortunately don't understand it enough to improve on it further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faster method.  Generate "in" and "out" records for when something gets counted. Then aggregate and use a running sum.

To get all minutes, throw in a `generate_series()` for the time period in question:

```
with tr as (
      select date_trunc('minute', (tr.in_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver')) as m,
             1 as inc
      from time_records tr
      union all
      select date_trunc('minute', (tr.out_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver')) + interval '1 minute' as m,
            -1 as inc
      from time_records tr
      union all
      select generate_series(date_trunc('minute', 
                                         min(tr.in_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver')),
                             date_trunc('minute',
                                         max(tr.out_datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver')),
                             interval '1 minute'
                            ), 0
      from time_records tr
     )
select m,
       sum(inc) as changes_at_inc,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by m) as running_count
from tr
group by m
order by m;
```

Comment: I had to remove an extra `)` and add `interval '1 min'` to get this to run, but I'm not sure I understand what's happening here? It returns way more than 1440 rows and takes longer than my original query.

Comment: Modifying your query further, I'm able to get something close to what I'm looking for: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n1ibdtf5Ri6oAsiFyYQnaK/1 but towards the end of the day (about 22:00 onwards) the values turn negative for some reason.